# sshxcute Auth Fail | JschException

Tags: java, unix, authentication, jsch

Im using sshxcute to connect to a unix server  from java.
While Connecting I get an error of :

> JschException : Auth fail

Please Let me know what can be the possible issue.

Here is a psedo code of what im using :

```
SSHExec ssh= null;
ConnBean cb = new ConnBean("servername","username","password");
SSHExec.getInstance(cb)
ssh.connect();
ssh.disconnect();
```

Also please let me know what can cause this ?